# .htaccess RewriteRule ReDirect driving me nuts (IUpdate 02)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

After much searching I found a very good clue that helped me take some important steps towards my goal. Everything is now working well except for the following:

I need to ReWrite or ReDirect to `www.example.com/go404` in these cases:

- `www.example.com`
- `www.example.com/`
- `example.com`
- `example.com/`

But not, of course, when they type

- `www.example.com/subdomain` or
- `example.com/subdomain`

Presently, my `.htaccess` code has this snippet added:

```
# This sends "just domain" visits to 404
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/go404 [R=301,L]

# This one makes a NON WWW become a WWW
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# This strips the trailing slash
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/(\?.*)?$ $1$2 [R=301,L]
```

Can anyone tell me how to set up the condition so it ONLY allows domains written without the trailing slash and/or subfolder string? As indicated above those should redirect to 404.

I'm trying to get our Magento site to respond as in the table below using `.htaccess` rewrites. For whatever reason, only some options work (marked as "Ok"). The others produce `www.example.com`, that I don't want (marked as "Fail").

| When visitor types | The (internal) result should be: |
| --- | --- |
| `www.example.com` | `www.example.com/go404` (Fail) |
| `www.example.com/` | `www.example.com/go404` (Fail) |
| `www.example.com/notfound` | `www.example.com/go404` (OK) |
| `www.example.com/subdomain` | `www.example.com/_subdomain` (OK) |
| `www.example.com/subdomain/` | `www.example.com/_subdomain` (OK) |
| `www.example.com/admin` | `www.example.com/admin` (OK) |
| `example.com` | `www.example.com/go404` (Fail) |
| `example.com/notfound` | `www.example.com/go404` (Fail) |
| `example.com/` | `www.example.com/go404` (Fail) |
| `example.com/subdomain` | `www.example.com/_subdomain` (Fail) |
| `example.com/subdomain/` | `www.example.com/_subdomain` (OK) |
| `example.com/admin` | `www.example.com/admin` (Fail) |

To keep things in order in our Root, all subdomains are folders called _subdomain. Visitors to the site only have to write `www.example.com/subdomain` and we add the underscore in front.

Notes:

- "notfound" is any string without a corresponding "_subdomain" folder
- "admin" is a valid exception: no underscore in front
- As you can see from the table above all addresses without the "www" fail. Also, I have two specific problems related to the "clean" domain + clean domain with trailing slash.

This is my complete `.htaccess` (I erased the comments to make it shorter):

```
addhandler x-httpd-php5-cgi .php5
addhandler x-httpd-php5-cgi .php
addhandler x-httpd-php-cgi .php4

Options -MultiViews
DirectoryIndex index.php

<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_value memory_limit 256M
php_value max_execution_time 18000
php_flag magic_quotes_gpc off
php_flag session.auto_start off
php_flag suhosin.session.cryptua off
php_flag zend.ze1_compatibility_mode Off
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_security.c>
SecFilterEngine Off
SecFilterScanPOST Off
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
SSLOptions StdEnvVars
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^api/([a-z][0-9a-z_]+)/?$ api.php?type=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^api/rest api.php?type=rest [QSA,L]
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRAC[EK]
RewriteRule .* - [L,R=405]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
</IfModule>

AddDefaultCharset Off

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>

Order allow,deny
Allow from all

<Files RELEASE_NOTES.txt>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$
RewriteRule ^example\.com/(admin)$ www.example.com/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ www.example.com/_$1  [L]
RewriteRule ^www\.example\.com/(admin)$ www.example.com/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^www\.example\.com/(.*)$ www.example.com/_$1
```

Comment: This post should not be tagged as magento related.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you got the 3rd case working with those rewriterules. They just should not work.

Here is what I would use:

```
#external redirect to www. version (to prevent duplicated content)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$
RewriteRule .* http://www.domain.com/$0 [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^/?$ /go404
RewriteRule ^/?(admin) - [L]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) /_$1  [L]
```

Comment: Gerben, thanks for your version but it is not working (I get a 500 error). I'm looking into the possible reasons why it works when it shouldn't and doesn't when it should.